# TFS2010: FactTestResult table in Tfs_Warehouse is missing data

Tags: tfs

We are running some reports against TFS 2010, in particular on the unit tests that ran against a particular build.

These reports after a certain date started returning no data. My investigation shows that there is no data in FactTestResult table after a certain date, while other tables, for example DimTestRun, have the data associated with the same test runs.

Of these two queries only the first one returns data:

```
SELECT * FROM FactTestResult WHERE TestRunSK = 58959

SELECT * FROM DimTestRun WHERE TestRunSK = 58959
```

[image]

But for an earlier TestRunSK both queries return data:

```
SELECT * FROM FactTestResult WHERE TestRunSK = 56582

SELECT * FROM DimTestRun WHERE TestRunSK = 56582
```

[image]

Any ideas on why the data is being lost for the FactTestResult table and if it can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go to the Warehouse Control Web Service, and check the Processing Status, then manually process the data warehouse relational database by following article [Manually Process the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237(v=vs.100).aspx).

To access the Warehouse Control Web Service:

1. Log on to the application-tier server.
2. Open Internet Explorer, type the following string in the Address bar, and then press ENTER:

-

```
http://localhost:8080/VirtualDirectory/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
```

If manually process Data Warehouse doesn't work, try to rebuild the data warehouse by following article [Rebuild the Data Warehouse and Analysis Services Cube](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668753(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: The Manual data processing did it! Took many hours and the incremental analysis processing is still running, but the report is already returning results.